# How to use the Trampoline type as the base monad of a transformer more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, trampolines

I have an array transformer type that exhibits interleaved effect layers to ensure a lawful effect implementation. You can easily read the structure from the type's `of` operation `const arrOfT = of => x => of([of(x)])`.

The type implements an effectful fold as its basic operation. I use a left fold, because the underlying array type is inherently strict:

```
const arrFoldT = chain => f => init => mmx =>
  chain(mmx) (mx => {
    const go = (acc, i) =>
      i === mx.length
        ? acc
        : chain(mx[i]) (x =>
            go(f(acc) (x), i + 1))
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ non-tail call position
    return go(init, 0);
  });
```

As you can see the implementation is not stack safe. However, stack safety is just another computational effect that can be encoded through a monad. I implemented one for the `Trampoline` type:

```
const monadRec = o => {
  while (o.tag === "Chain")
    o = o.f(o.x);

  return o.tag === "Of"
    ? o.x
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown case"));
};

const recChain = mx => fm =>
  mx.tag === "Chain" ? Chain(mx.x) (x => recChain(mx.f(x)) (fm))
    : mx.tag === "Of" ? fm(mx.x)
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown case"));

const Chain = x => f =>
  ({tag: "Chain", f, x});

const Of = x =>
  ({tag: "Of", x});
```

While the implementations are straightforward the application is not. I am pretty sure I am applying it all wrong:

```
const mmx = Of(
  Array(1e5)
    .fill(Chain(1) (x => Of(x))));
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ redundant continuation

const main = arrFoldT(recChain)
  (acc => y => recMap(x => x + y) (acc))
    (Of(0))
      (mmx);

monadRec(main); // 100000
```

I need to use `Chain` when creating the large effectful array, because `Of` signals the the control flow to break out of the trampoline. With `Chain` on the other hand I have to specifiy a redundant continuation.

My first idea was to flip `Chain`'s arguments and rely on partial application, but this doesn't work with the current implemenetation.

Is there a way to use the type more efficiently?

Here is a working example:

```js
// ARRAYT

const arrFoldT = chain => f => init => mmx =>
  chain(mmx) (mx => {
    const go = (acc, i) =>
      i === mx.length
        ? acc
        : chain(mx[i]) (x =>
            go(f(acc) (x), i + 1))

    return go(init, 0);
  });

// TRAMPOLINE

const monadRec = o => {
  while (o.tag === "Chain")
    o = o.f(o.x);

  return o.tag === "Of"
    ? o.x
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown case"));
};

const Chain = x => f =>
  ({tag: "Chain", f, x});

const Of = x =>
  ({tag: "Of", x});

// Functor

const recMap = f => tx =>
  Of(f(tx.x));

// Monad

const recChain = mx => fm =>
  mx.tag === "Chain" ? Chain(mx.x) (x => recChain(mx.f(x)) (fm))
    : mx.tag === "Of" ? fm(mx.x)
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown case"));

const recOf = Of;

// MAIN

const mmx = Of(
  Array(1e5)
    .fill(Chain(1) (x => Of(x))));

const main = arrFoldT(recChain)
  (acc => y => recMap(x => x + y) (acc))
    (Of(0))
      (mmx);

console.log(
  monadRec(main)); // 100000
```

Comment: Iirc [the fantasyland spec has special `ChainRec` type](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chainrec) specifically made for this, which your array transformer would have to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the definition of your array monad transformer is wrong.

```hs
ArrayT m a = m (Array (m a))
```

The above type definition does not correctly interleave the underlying monad.

Following is an example value of the above data type.

```js
of([of(1), of(2), of(3)])
```

There are several problems with this data type.

1. There is no effect for the end of the array.
2. The effects are not ordered. Hence, they can be executed in any order.
3. The underlying monad wraps the individual elements as well as the entire array. This is just wrong.

Following is an example value of the correct array monad transformer type.

```js
of([1, of([2, of([3, of([])])])])
```

Note that.

1. There is an effect for the end of the array.
2. The effects are ordered. This is because the data type is defined recursively.
3. The underlying monad wraps the individual steps of the array. It doesn't wrap the entire array again.

Now, I understand why you want to define `ArrayT m a = m (Array (m a))`. If `m = Identity` then you get back an actual `Array a`, which supports random access of elements.

```js
of([of(1), of(2), of(3)]) === [1, 2, 3]
```

On the other hand, the recursive array monad transformer type returns a linked list when `m = Identity`.

```js
of([1, of([2, of([3, of([])])])]) === [1, [2, [3, []]]]
```

However, there's no way to create a lawful array monad transformer type which also returns an actual array when the underlying monad is `Identity`. This is because monad transformers are inherently algebraic data structures, and arrays are not algebraic.

The closest you can get is by defining `ArrayT m a = Array (m a)`. However, this would only satisfy the monad laws when the underlying monad is commutative.

Just remember, when defining a monad transformer data type.

1. The underlying monad must wrap at most one value at a time.
2. The underlying monad must be nested, to correctly order and interleave effects.

---

Coming back, the `Trampoline` monad is just the `Free` monad. We can define it as follows.

```js
// pure : a -> Free a
const pure = value => ({ constructor: pure, value });

// bind : Free a -> (a -> Free b) -> Free b
const bind = monad => arrow => ({ constructor: bind, monad, arrow });

// thunk : (() -> Free a) -> Free a
const thunk = eval => ({ constructor: thunk, eval });

// MonadFree : Monad Free
const MonadFree = { pure, bind };

// evaluate : Free a -> a
const evaluate = expression => {
    let expr = expression;
    let stack = null;

    while (true) {
        switch (expr.constructor) {
            case pure:
                if (stack === null) return expr.value;
                expr = stack.arrow(expr.value);
                stack = stack.stack;
                break;
            case bind:
                stack = { arrow: expr.arrow, stack };
                expr = expr.monad;
                break;
            case thunk:
                expr = expr.eval();
        }
    }
};
```

I'll also copy my implementation of the array monad transformer from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64480784/783743).

```js
// Step m a = null | { head : a, tail : ListT m a }
// ListT m a = m (Step m a)

// nil : Monad m -> ListT m a
const nil = M => M.pure(null);

// cons : Monad m -> a -> ListT m a -> ListT m a
const cons = M => head => tail => M.pure({ head, tail });

// foldr : Monad m -> (a -> m b -> m b) -> m b -> ListT m a -> m b
const foldr = M => f => a => m => M.bind(m)(step =>
    step ? f(step.head)(foldr(M)(f)(a)(step.tail)) : a);
```

Thus, when the underlying monad is `Free` then the operations are stack safe.

```js
// replicate :: Number -> a -> ListT Free a
const replicate = n => x => n ?
    cons(MonadFree)(x)(thunk(() => replicate(n - 1)(x))) :
    nil(MonadFree);

// map : (a -> b) -> Free a -> Free b
const map = f => m => bind(m)(x => pure(f(x)));

// add : Number -> Free Number -> Free Number
const add = x => map(y => x + y);

// result : Free Number
const result = foldr(MonadFree)(add)(pure(0))(replicate(1000000)(1));

console.log(evaluate(result)); // 1000000
```

Putting it all together.

```js
// pure : a -> Free a
const pure = value => ({ constructor: pure, value });

// bind : Free a -> (a -> Free b) -> Free b
const bind = monad => arrow => ({ constructor: bind, monad, arrow });

// thunk : (() -> Free a) -> Free a
const thunk = eval => ({ constructor: thunk, eval });

// MonadFree : Monad Free
const MonadFree = { pure, bind };

// evaluate : Free a -> a
const evaluate = expression => {
    let expr = expression;
    let stack = null;

    while (true) {
        switch (expr.constructor) {
            case pure:
                if (stack === null) return expr.value;
                expr = stack.arrow(expr.value);
                stack = stack.stack;
                break;
            case bind:
                stack = { arrow: expr.arrow, stack };
                expr = expr.monad;
                break;
            case thunk:
                expr = expr.eval();
        }
    }
};

// Step m a = null | { head : a, tail : ListT m a }
// ListT m a = m (Step m a)

// nil : Monad m -> ListT m a
const nil = M => M.pure(null);

// cons : Monad m -> a -> ListT m a -> ListT m a
const cons = M => head => tail => M.pure({ head, tail });

// foldr : Monad m -> (a -> m b -> m b) -> m b -> ListT m a -> m b
const foldr = M => f => a => m => M.bind(m)(step =>
    step ? f(step.head)(foldr(M)(f)(a)(step.tail)) : a);

// replicate :: Number -> a -> ListT Free a
const replicate = n => x => n ?
    cons(MonadFree)(x)(thunk(() => replicate(n - 1)(x))) :
    nil(MonadFree);

// map : (a -> b) -> Free a -> Free b
const map = f => m => bind(m)(x => pure(f(x)));

// add : Number -> Free Number -> Free Number
const add = x => map(y => x + y);

// result : Free Number
const result = foldr(MonadFree)(add)(pure(0))(replicate(1000000)(1));

console.log(evaluate(result)); // 1000000
```

Comment: Arrays are not algebraic, hence they cannot be transformed into a lawful transformer, that makes sense. Interestingly, the type behaves like a transformer if you stick to the index. I've created a `ArrayT`/`Maybe` and `ArrayT`/`Writer` stack and it worked as expected. There are no guarantees that this holds for every monad, of course.

Comment: Btw, you can think of the entire array wrapped in the base effect as the nil case, i.e. the base effect happens at least once. I know that this is only possible in a messy untyped setting, but maybe if you squeeze hard enough..

Comment: "Interestingly, the type behaves like a transformer if you stick to the index." Do you mean arrays of fixed length?

Comment: No, the entire array wrapped in an effect is not the base case. The problem is that if you want to access the first element of the array then you'll need to execute two effects. One effect for the entire array and another effect for the value. That is incorrect.

Comment: I assume an immutable array and the policy to only traverse it using the given index. I guess the additional effect doesn't matter if you compose with `Either` etc. It probably bites for monads that encode side effects like IO/Task and I dunno the behavior with `Writer`, for instance. The transformer is broken and probably not worth the effort.